# Exception has occurred: AttributeError '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the below error in Python3:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'shape'

```
import requests

from contextlib import closing

import csv

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv'

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:

    f = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in r.iter_lines())
    a = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in a:
        print(row)

print(a.shape)
```

Comment: You probably confused `csv` standard module with `pandas.read_csv` which uses Numpy array under the hood and exposes `.shape` attribute.

Comment: And what have you tried to overcome the error? Why did you call `shape` on that object after all?

Answer (score 2):

The [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) type does not have a `.shape` attribute. I usually do something like this

```
a = csv.reader(f, ...)
rows = list(a)
for row in rows:
    # ...
print(len(rows))
```